Spring boot [elasticsearch] cluster -x_content_parse_exception- Unexpected character (‘\’ (code 92)): was expecting double-quote
I am using elastic version 8+ with spring boot elasticsearch 5.2.0 dependency. I want to query my index with Odata $filter. I have configured my parser for Odata and it's generating below query json for following query: $filter=degreeLevel eq masters
But from cluster I am getting 400 with following error:
Resolved [UncategorizedElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [x_content_parse_exception] [2:4] Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (byte[])"{
  \"bool\" : {
    \"must\" : [
      {
        \"match\" : {
          \"degreeLevel\" : {
            \"query\" : \"masters\",
            \"operator\" : \"OR\",
            \"prefix_length\" : 0,
            \"max_expansions\" : 50,
            \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,
            \"lenient\" : false,
            \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",
            \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,
            \"boost\" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],

Reference link: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-search-failed-x-content-parse-exception-2-4-unexpected-character-code-92-was-expecting-double-quote/356632/5?u=thatelasticguy
It should return the query result as excpeted.

From your linked ES issue: "This exception means that the request being sent to Elasticsearch contains those \ escape characters, so it isn't valid JSON". So how do you produce this query and how do you send it to ES?

had another look at that linked discussion - it seems you are using spring-data-opensearch?

@P.J.Meisch I am using spring-boot-elasticsearch and that handles sending the query json. And yes, I have a dependency that uses spring-data-opensearch.
